# localhost redirecting to search page

Tags: wordpress

I have dowloaded wordpress 3.5 and xampp and they are succeessfully insatlled in windows 7 and also changed the wp-config.php file in wordpress and placed it in ht docs and also created a database.  My problem is when i load localhost/phpmyadmin it appears and when i load localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php it takes me to my home page which is http://static.flipora.com/websearch.html?ref_type=redirect&src_type=bg&tv=7.104&t=7.104&u=12606685. It takes here whenever i type localhost/(anything). Please tell me there is problem with my xampp or wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely malware.

See [this](http://www.remove-malware.info/removal-instructions/remove-static-flipora-com-search-flipora/) to remove it

Comment: I removed it but now it is redirecting me to http://search.conduit.com/corse/?ctid=CT3225826&octid=CT3225826&SearchSource=11&CUI=UN56305248243734240&SSPV=EB_SSPV&Lay=1&UM=&fq=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fnewsite&SAT=SAT_ID. dont know what's wrong

Comment: That's a great collection you got there. I searched in google "Remove search.conduit.com" and got [this](http://forums.anvisoft.com/viewtopic-45-5152-0.html)

Comment: I'm trying that too. can this be a problem of php also?

Comment: It says that "Your Community Toolbar detected that the page you wanted was not found, and offered you an alternative, more helpful Search page. This takes the place of the generic page usually displayed, called a 404 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/404_error) or DNS error page."

Comment: Search those errors in google. Almost everytime someone already solved that problem. Here's someon who had that error: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/931684](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/931684). Just uninstall all suspicious toolbars that you might have in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers need `http://` prepended before *localhost* and similar URLs to work. On Chrome I need to add the `http://` part to access *localproject.dev* URLs properly (otherwise it redirects to Google search). Firefox seems to work normally with these kinds of URLs.